# Limit woocommerce category description

Tags: woocommerce, limit

If i click on a product category from woocommerce is show the full description. People need to scroll a lot to see the products. We can move the product description to the Bottom, but i don't like it. I need help with the following:

How can i limit the woocommerce category description with a read more button? If i click on it it will expand the full description on the page. The default read more function from wordpress doesnt work. Someone knows how to fix this?  PLease let me know!